# Laravel: How to secure APIs for iOS and Android apps

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am making a backend CMS for my android and iOS app and have implemented the APIs. But I am struggling with securing them. I have tried using Laravel Passport but I failed to use it. I want to ask if my apporach to secure them is right? Should I use passport or is there some other way to secure my apis? And how do I do it? Any help will be appreciated.

I am using laravel 5.4.

Comment: You may want to use jwt.

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: use laravel passport because passport is also jwt and also easy to implement.